# Open a url in Windows Metro App via Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Normally, when I use `<a href="_URL_"></a>` in my metro application, the url is opening in the default web browser. I don't want to do this with anchor, I want to do the same behavior via Javascript and as async. But I don't know how to open the url with default browser.

Here is my code:

```
var $aTag = $("<a/>").click(function (event) {
    showYesNoDialog(
        "Do you approve?", 
        "The link will be opened in another window. Do you approve?", 
        "Yes", // Text of yes button
        "No",  // Text of no button
        function () { // Behavior of yes button
            // I tried this but nothing happened.
            window.location.href = _URL_; // Should open in chrome or default web browser
        },
        function () { // Behavior of no button
            // do nothing
        }
    );
});
```

What I also tried is that:

```
$("<a href='" + _URL_ + "'></a>").click();
```

But this didn't work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer while searching on google.
[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

I used this code to open the url out the metro app and it worked in my situation:

```
window.open(_URL_, '_blank');
window.focus();
```

Comment: Cool! Simple Javascript haha!

Comment: I didn't think that this will work, so I didn't try it before :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch an actual application from within Metro, but what you can do is launch a file with associated program, and that should give you the functionality you need.

[Check Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec)

The sample covers files and URI's - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701476

Comment: I'm not dealing with files, I needed to open a web page. Thanks for interesting, finally I found my answer and I wrote it.